# Having no children at all or having only one is becoming a norm. (Is this sentence okay?)

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

> Having no children at all or having only one is becoming a norm.

The sentence is okay?  a norm or the norm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are possible: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/norm) gives examples of both. Using "a norm" is slightly more technical (it recognises that there are different norms for different cultures).

While we often talk about "norms of behaviour" using the plural,  "the norm" is idiomatic and common in this sense.